# How to query if entity exists in app engine NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around NDB. For some reason it's just not clicking. The thing i'm struggling with the most is the whole key/kind/ancestor structure.

I'm just trying to store a simple set of Json data. When i store data, i want to check beforehand to see if a duplicate entity exists (based on the key, not the data) so i don't store a duplicate entity.

```
class EarthquakeDB(ndb.Model):
  data = ndb.JsonProperty()
  datetime = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, to store data:

```
quake_entry = EarthquakeDB(parent=ndb.Key('Earthquakes', quake['id']), data=quake).put()
```

So my questions are:

1. How do i check to see if that particular key exists before i insert more data?
2. How would i go about pulling that data out to read based on the key?

Answer (score 3):

After some trial and error, and with the assistance of voscausa, here is what i came up with to solve the problem. The data is being read in via a for loop.

```
for quake in data:
  quake_entity = EarthquakeDB.get_by_id(quake['id'])
  if quake_entity:
    continue
  else:
    quate_entity = EarthquakeDB(id=quake['id'], data=quake).put()
```

Comment: this solution ends up (potentially, if data is a big collection) doing a lot of reads and writes to the datastore. For collections, you might be better of just doing *ndb.put_multi([EarthquakeDB(id=q['id'], data=q) for q in data])* which will silently overwrite by id. If you still want to avoid overwrites based on id, you can ndb.get_multi everything first, then check by id in memory, and finally write the new ones

Comment: Another possible problem could be due to a failed write ( say, due to some unhandled exception ), the memcache would still hold the entity with the key which the user attempted to commit to NDB but failed. If `get_by_id()` is called on such a memcache present key, I think it can falsely return the entity ( from memcache ) which never went to NDB. I am not sure but I suspect this problem with the approach mentioned in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you do not provide a full NDB key (only a parent) you will always insert a unique key.
But you use your own entity id for the parent? Why?

I think you mean:

```
quake_entry = EarthquakeDB(id=quake['id'], data=quake)
quake_entry.put()
```

To get it, you can use:

```
quate_entry = ndb.Key('Earthquakes', quake['id']).get()
```

Here you can find two excellent videos about the datastore, strong consistency and entity groups. [Datastore Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQazhzcC-rg) and [Datastore Query, Index and Transaction.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4CiMWy0J70)

Comment: Ah. I didn't know i could use the id= to set the key. That makes much more sense. I still need to know how to query the datastore to see if an entity exists though. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use get_or_insert. It will insert the data if the entity does not exist: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert